# Redirect user after login in laravel 5.1

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1

I am trying to implement a feature where, after logging in, a user gets redirected to a URL depending on their role. I have the roles part set up, but I'm having trouble testing the user's properties immediately after login.

I followed the instructions [here](https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/how-to-make-user-login-and-registration-laravel-5-1/) to create a user login page. I have an `AuthController` that looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    protected $redirectTo = '/test';
    ...
}
```

My `__construct()` function validates the user, but I don't know how to access the user object only immediately after login. This is what I presently have:

```
 public function __construct() {
     $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);

     if ( \Auth::check() ) {
         $user = \Auth::user();
         if ( $user->admin() ) {
         // an admin
             $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
         } else {
         // it's a client
             $this->redirectTo = '/client/dashboard';

         }
     }

     $user = \Auth::user();
     if ( is_object($user) ) {
     } else {
         $this->redirectTo = '/auth-not-object';
     }
 }
```

When I first attempt to log in with an administrator account, I get to the path `/auth-not-object`, because there isn't any authenticated user object at that point.

After having attempted to log in, but getting a bad redirect, when I revisit the `/login` url, I get redirected to `/home`, which I believe is the default `$redirectTo` in the traits this class uses. So that means we've passed the AuthController `__construct()` method without having changed the `$redirectTo`, even though there is an authenticated user.

I've found other questions, such as [How to add extra logic on login condition in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032556/how-to-add-extra-logic-on-login-condition-in-laravel-5-2) and [laravel redirect to url after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240906/laravel-redirect-to-url-after-login), but I don't understand how to apply those answers. For instance, the accepted answer to the second question shows new methods, `getCredentials()` and `login()`, which don't exist in the poster's original class. I am not sure in what class to add them, or where to call them from, in my codebase.

Other similar answers show a radically different way of authenticating users, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35952713/151841). It seems that, to use that solution, I would need to re-write my code, and forgo the use of the traits, which include bonus features like login throttling and so on.

Is there a way I can redirect users based on role after login, while still using these built-in traits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if the 5.1 auth is the same as the 5.2 auth, but if it is, remove all that from the construct and add this method:

```
    protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated( Request $request, $throttles, $guard )
    {
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts( $request );
        }
        if ( method_exists( $this, 'authenticated' ) ) {
            return $this->authenticated( $request, Auth::guard( $guard )->user() );
        }
        return redirect()->intended( $this->redirectTo );
    }
```

this is the method that will determine the redirect and you have access to the user object.

**EDIT**

I take the above back, just add the following to your controller;

```
protected function authenticated( $request, $user ) {
    return redirect()->intended( $user->admin() ? '/admin' : '/client/dashboard' );
}
```

That should work nicely

Comment: Also remove `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);`? That was the only piece that came out of the box.

Comment: I'm getting the error `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::handleUserWasAuthenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given`, even after I've changed the method signature to `protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated( \App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request $request, $throttles, $guard ) { ... `

Comment: Edited my answer to a better solution (just seen the second half of the method above, doh!)

Comment: Thanks so much, this has vexed me for a while! : )